# Assign class for .map() values

Tags: jquery

For example I have a function like below:

```
OrSovSKeyword = $('.OrsovWord').map(function() {
    // get text 
     return $(this).text()
    // get result as array
).get();
```

I'd like to assign class for each result it generates, therefore I used this:

```
 OrSovSKeyword = $('.OrsovWord').map(function() {
    // get text 
     return <span class="123"> $(this).text() </span>
    // get result as array
).get();
```

However this returns something like below in my code:

[image]

As you can see there's two `\` in between makes me can access the element by getting it's class, how can I fix it?

Update:

```
var sovName = $("#input_SovName_Adv").val();
var sovSKeyword = "";

OrSovSKeyword = $('.OrsovWord').map(function() {
    return  '<span class="Or">' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
}).get();

AndSovSKeyword = $('.AndsovWord').map(function() {
    return  '<span class="And">' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
}).get();

$("#insertedNewSov").append('<tr>' +
    '<td class="sovNames">' + sovName + '</td>' +
    '<td class="sovKeywordArr">' + JSON.stringify(AndSovSKeyword).replace(/\[/g,'').replace(/\]/g,'').replace(/\"/g,'') + ',' +  JSON.stringify(OrSovSKeyword).replace(/\[/g,'').replace(/\]/g,'').replace(/\"/g,'') + '<p class="right"><i class="fa fa-times removeRow" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i></p></td>' +
'</tr>');
```

Comment: Could you please post your actual code. What you've got in your question would never work due to the multitude of syntax errors

Comment: ok i'd uploaded those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you're using `JSON.stringify` on your arrays before appending them to the DOM - hence the odd formatting. You need to `join()` them together instead. Try this:

```
$("#insertedNewSov").append('<tr>' +
    '<td class="sovNames">' + sovName + '</td>' +
    '<td class="sovKeywordArr">' + AndSovSKeyword.join('') + ',' + OrSovSKeyword.join('') + '<p class="right"><i class="fa fa-times removeRow" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i></p></td>' +
'</tr>');
```